# Ruby on rails - update table with jquery GET method

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am using Rails and jquery.

My problem is when I try to update the resources table, by sending the parameters with the get method it doesn't work.

My controller

```
class ResourcesController < ApplicationController
       ...

       # PUT /resources/18
       def update
          @resource.update_attributes(params[:resource])
       end

       ...
end
```

javascript file

```
$.get("/resources/18", {color: blue, size: 15}, function(data)
{

});
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The `update` action expects a `PUT`, not a `GET`. So you have to do a different request.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'put',
  url: '/resources/18', 
  data: {resources: {color: blue, size: 15}}
});
```

Comment: Well, the server log or the browser console show some errors?

Comment: no errors, I have tried data: {resource: {color: blue, size: 15}} without the 's' but still the same it doesn't work.

Comment: And even with success: function(msg) { alert("this is a test")}  no message appear